# how to add a prefix to array in javascript, but just in values that still doesn't have it?

Tags: javascript

I have an javascript array:

```
var arr = ["images/1.jpg", "2.jpg", "some.jpg"];
```

Adding the prefix images/ should result in this:
The code should have to exclude the values that already had the prefix.

```
newArr = ["images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/some.jpg"];
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done an any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: You can use .map method to check if the prefix is present or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to only add the prefix if it isn't already these.

In the example below I used [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to only add a prefix if it's not already there.

```js
const magic = (arr, prefix) => arr 
  .map(str => str.startsWith(prefix) ? str : `${prefix}${str}`)

console.log(magic(["images/1.jpg", "2.jpg", "some.jpg"], 'images/'))
```